# Import Asset to Rive

Tags: rive

I have a logo of my company, I would like to create and animation of fading image and use it as a splash screen, I can't figure out how to import the logo on https://preview-web.rive.app/ and start doing the work.

Answer (score 0):

You can drag and drop an .svg of your logo files into Rive. Give it a few seconds to show and it may not be in the middle of the document. I use Affinity Designer which can export vectors files as SVG. I tried using .psd exported from A.D. but couldn't get that to work for some reason. You may need to scale the vector image down depending on the original size when imported. The layers are also kept on import such as "arm" "leg" "head" etc. A new artboard is automatically created with the vector, so no need to create one before hand.